# Add a Hyperlink to Images that goes to Another Page within a CSS wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three images on an HTML home page. I want the user to be able to click on the images to go to another page. I have this so far:

```
#features ul li.feature-1 {
    background: url('../images/pavilion_small.png') no-repeat top center;
}
#features ul li.feature-2 {
    background: url('../images/dtc_small.png') no-repeat top center;
}
#features ul li.feature-3 {
    background: url('../images/downtown_small.png') no-repeat top center;
}
```

I am a little confused how to hyperlink the images to another page. I've looked some things up online about it, but since I am fairly new to this, they seemed a little confusing to me. Could someone explain what I should be doing to accomplish this? Thanks!

Also, here is my HTML:

```
<div id="features">
        <p id="homeValue"></p>
        <h3>Find Out What Your Home is Worth</h3>
        <center><h4>Begin by clicking your town name</h4></center>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li class="feature-1">
            <h4><a href="https://d.github.io/Real-Estate/a.html">A</a></h4> <!-- This links only the text to the appropriate page -->
            <p>sdfhsfkjs</p>
            </li>
            <li class="feature-2">
            <h4>B</h4>
            <p>sfkljsfklsjf</p>
            </li>
            <li class="feature-3">
            <h4>C</h4>
            <p>sdfkljsdlkfj</p>
            </li>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML. The CSS is only half of what we need. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can use an anchor tag `<a href="...new page...">...img content...</a>`

Comment: @disinfor sorry about that... done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Keep images in an Anchor tag

```
<li>
    <a href="https://yoursite.com/yourlink">
        <img alt="image" src="https://www.yoursite.com/images/youimage.png">
    </a>
</li>
```

Or image from stylesheet

```
<li class="feature-1">
    <a href="https://yoursite.com/yourlink"></a>
</li>
```

But the problem here is image is not inside you a tag

Comment: Yep, go with an <img> tag inside the <a>, then you can have alt text to make it more accessible.

Comment: @Ryano an image doesn't necessarily have to be accessible as a background image if it's presentation only and decorative. If the background images contained text that was important to the presented information, then going with an inline with alt text would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `li` content in an `a` tag. You still get the benefit of having the background image, but the entire content block will link to a new URL:

```css
#features ul li.feature-1 {
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/200x200') no-repeat top center;
}

#features ul li.feature-2 {
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/200x200') no-repeat top center;
}

#features ul li.feature-3 {
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/200x200') no-repeat top center;
}

#features ul li a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="features">
  <p id="homeValue"></p>
  <h3>Find Out What Your Home is Worth</h3>
  <center>
    <h4>Begin by clicking your town name</h4>
  </center>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li class="feature-1">
        <a href="#">
          <h4>A</h4>
          <!-- This links only the text to the appropriate page -->
          <p>sdfhsfkjs</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="feature-2">
        <a href="#">
          <h4>B</h4>
          <p>sfkljsfklsjf</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="feature-3">
        <a href="#">
          <h4>C</h4>
          <p>sdfkljsdlkfj</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I set the `a` to display as block, so no matter where you hover on the `li` the area will be clickable.